# Probability clarification

Tags: probability

Consider the reading habits of the X class. If we know that
30% of the class students read USA Today daily, 40% read Salt
Lake Tribune daily and 10% read both of them daily, what is the
percentage of the X class students who do not read these two
newspapers daily?

can someone help me with a sol with explanation?

Comment: Wrong fora? Perhaps you meant *Math.Stackexchange*?

Answer (score 0):

What percentage **only** read the USA Today daily?
It is $30\%-10\%=20\%$.

What percentage read either?
It is $20\%+40\%=60\%$

So what percentage read neither?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

P(USA Today daily) = p(a) = 30%
p( Salt Lake Tribune daily) = p(b) = 40%
and p(a n b) = 10%

p(E) = p(a) +p(b) - p(a n b) => 30 + 40-10 = 60%

p( who read neither) = 1- p(E) = 40%

Is this correct?